# swap information from mysql query

Tags: php, pdo

Literally can't think of a better way to phrase this.

So, I need to update two columns in a DB and have them swap some information. I feel like this could be done simply and i've been over thinking it -- mostly because right now the whole things being done through 3 different functions in a PHP class (see below).

```
function hotSinglesInYourArea()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT
                    citizens.cid as id, 
                    citizens.gender as gender
                FROM
                    citizens
                WHERE
                    citizens.status <> 'married'";
        $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $data = [];
        try { 
            $que->execute();
            while($row = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $data[] = $row; 
            }
            }catch(PDOException $e){}
        return $data;
    }
    function hookemup()
    {
        $data = $this->hotSinglesInYourArea();
        $count = (count($data))-1;
        if($count >= 0)
        {
        mt_srand(time());
        $rand = mt_rand(0,$count);
        $citizenA = $data[$rand];
        sleep(1);
        mt_srand(time());
        $rand = mt_rand(0, $count);
        $citizenB = $data[$rand];
        if($citizenA['gender'] <> $citizenB['gender'])
        {
            $this->getMarried($citizenA['id'],$citizenB['id']);
        }
        else
        {
            #echo $citizenA['id'].'|'.$citizenB['id'];  
            sleep(2);
        }
        }
    }
    function getMarried($a, $b)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE
                    citizens
                SET 
                    partner = :a,
                    status = 'married'
                WHERE 
                    cid = :b;
                UPDATE
                    citizens
                SET
                    partner = :b2,
                    status = 'married'
                WHERE
                    cid = :a2";
    $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $que->bindParam(':a', $a);
    $que->bindParam(':a2', $a);
    $que->bindParam(':b', $b);
    $que->bindParam(':b2', $b);
    try {   $que->execute(); $que->nextRowset(); } catch(PDOException $e){}
    }
```

So those functions (I appoligize for the names of them, i'm just using things i can remember) all serve one purpose -- they find 'citizens' that are not married and then marry them. hotSinglesInYourArea finds the ones that are single, Hookemup randomly chooses one and then getmarried actually changes the DB.

As i've said I'm wondering if there is a way i'm over looking that would make this work in a single function (or at least less functions)

Comment: What is the question? Looks like you already have the update

Answer (score 0):

are you just trying to simplify the UPDATE statement? If so, you could use a [CASE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html). Your SQL can become:

```
function getMarried($a, $b)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE
                citizens
            SET 
                partner = CASE cid WHEN :b THEN :a ELSE :b END,
                status = 'married'
            WHERE 
                cid in (:b, :a)";
...
```